# Java compiler error. Cannot find symbol

Tags: java, swing, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

Why am I getting this error when the SystemController class is in the same directory?

```
sgs$ javac Main.java 

Main.java:27: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SystemController
location: class sgs.Main
        SystemController sc = new SystemController();
        ^
Main.java:27: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class SystemController
location: class sgs.Main
        SystemController sc = new SystemController();
                                  ^
2 errors
```

---

```
package sgs;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        boolean loginSuccess = false;
        //Login login = new Login();
        //login.setVisible(true);
        //login.loadAccounts("files/accounts.txt");

        SystemController sc = new SystemController();
    sc.setVisible(true);
        sc.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

Comment: please show an `ls` in the same directory and the `SystemController` class. I suppose a mis-spelling.

Comment: About.java EditComponent.java  Messages.java Account.java          FileRead.java  NuclearSource.java AddComponent.form FileWrite.java PasswordRecovery.form AddComponent.java         Graph.java PasswordRecovery.java BufferedImageBuilder.java  Help.java ProduceReport.form
Bundle.properties Hub.java ProduceReport.java
City.java HydroSource.java SolarSource.java
CoalSource.java ImagePanel.java Sound.java
Console.java Login.form Source.java DeleteComponent.form SystemController.form DeleteComponent.java SystemController.java
Edge.java Login.java Vertex.java
 Main.java WindSource.java

Comment: not sure what it was, but I create another class called Main2 which the main file in it and now it works fine if I compile that class.  Weird I know.... the code is exactly the same.

Comment: main method I mean, not main file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you didn't compile `SystemController` on which `Main` depends. So either compile manually `SystemController` before to compile `Main` (but that will be painful on the long term if the number of classes grows) or compile everything together and let the compiler calculates the compilation order (better IMO). Something like this:

```
$ pwd
/path/to/sgs
$ cd ..
$ javac sgs/*.java
$ java -cp . sgs.Main
```

EDIT: From the error you posted as comment, I can see that you are using [GNU GCJ](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/) which [doesn't fully support Swing](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/faq.html#2_5). Please switch to Sun JDK or OpenJDK. Both should be available as package, just make sure to make it the default Java after install (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java for Ubuntu or a Debian based distro, find out how to do this for another distro).

Comment: java sgs.Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sgs.SystemController
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at sgs.Main.main(Main.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.swing.GroupLayout not found in gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader{urls=[file:./], parent=gnu.gcj.runtime.ExtensionClassLoader{urls=[], parent=null}}
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at gnu.gcj.runtime.SystemClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.10)

Comment: I think that Netbeans uses its own JDK which is not the same that you are using on the command line (you are using `gcj`). Typing `java -version` in a console would confirm this. I've edited my answer to provide more guidance.

Comment: OK so I updated my java version.
java version "1.6.0_16"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_16-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 14.2-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: However when I compile all java files get a .class file, but the SystemController.java file gets 13 different class files.

Comment: Because it's a Swing class created by a designer and it contains  many inner classes which is very common in Swing code. But... so what? :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you compiled SystemController ?

try

```
javac *.java
```

Also, remember to specify your classpath where the Swing classes are.

```
javac -cp classpath *.java
```

Comment: javac *.java
Note: Login.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Comment: Although that compiled everything, but it still get the same error stated in my original post